# install linux-headers for kernel 5.13 on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I recently installed the `5.13.1-051301-generic` kernel on ubuntu 20.04 (because it should support my WWAN module).

Now I'm trying to install displaylink drivers, but can't because of `missing linux headers for running kernel`.

```
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.4.0-55.153  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.4.0-55.153 install script called: 
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Unsatisfied dependencies. Missing component: Linux headers for running kernel, 5.13.1-051301-generic.
This is a fatal error, cannot install DisplayLink Linux Software.
```

Is there a way to install those headers? I already tried to install those but then I run into the problem of having the wrong libc6 version.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.13.1-051301-generic:
 linux-headers-5.13.1-051301-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.33); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2.
```

Comment: I don't think You can do that. Personally I went forward and upgraded to `21.04` to be able to use mainline kernels.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz thanks! That's what I ended up doing as well!